# Excel Solver with more than 100 contraints

Tags: excel

I want to find a quadratic equation that is always above my scatter data. I am using Excel Solver with the following formulation:

[image]

Here Column A and B contains my data.

Column C is the predicted Y.  E.g.: =$H$2*B3^2 + $H$3*B3 + $H$4

Column D is the difference between predict and actual Y. E.g.: C3-A3

I am minimizing the sum of column D which is in cell I2. i.e. =SUM(D3:D290)

My problem is that here I need to restrict the number of constraints to 100 but I have 288 rows, i.e. I want first constraint to be $D$3:$D$230 >= 0.

I tried to find a solution with different tools like R, MatLab, Python but no luck.
Can someone please help me with it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: OLS regression always has the residuals sum to 0

Comment: The question is too broad for tag spamming as you did. A Matlab, Python, or R user cannot take your picture and submit a coherent, simplified answer. If you would like to learn more about optimization in general or specific language execution, broadly stating that you are having Excel problems is not enough.